# JPA/Hibernate - Use unique constraint as primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I have the following problem, I have a already existing table with three fields field1, field2, field3. Field1 is actually a foreign key (**@OneToOne**) to another table. All field2 and field3 can be null, so I can't set a primary key for all three fields. In the database there is a UniqueConstraint for field1+field2+field3.

```
field1 | field2 | field 3
 1     |   1    |   null
 1     |  null  |   2
 3     |   1    |   null
```

I've tried several solutions with JPA/Hibernate but could not find a good one.
Without defining a **@Id** JPA can not work (of course). Defining the three fields in a **@Embeddable** and reuse it with **@EmbeddedId** creates a primary key over all three fields which do not allow null values.

Is there any other solution than change the existing table and add a auto generated id for each row?

Thank you so much & best regards!

Comment: What are Field2, Field3 used for? Are they keys in another table? Note that Field1 has a ManyToOne relationship to the parent table, the id 1 is in there twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as below?

```
@Table(
    name="xxx", 
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(name="my_unique_key", columnNames={"field1", "field2", "field3"})
)
```